# Generate dummy values if the Column data (X,Y,Z) is absent for a date

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table A as :
[image]

and I need to generate output like below:

[image]

So, whenever x,y,z column values for "CODE" is missing for a particular date, we need to generate dummy rows with 0 values as showing in the output.

Comment: What's the expected result if a date (in the range) has no rows at all?

Comment: Also show us your current SQL attempt.

Comment: If we dont have value x,y,x in code column for a particular date then we need to generate dummy rows for x,y,z

Comment: Do a _self OUTER JOIN_.

Comment: do you have a table with all the possible values for code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @temp table(id int IDENTITY(1,1), rowDate date, code varchar(1), val int);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('01.08.2023', 'x', 100);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('01.08.2023', 'y', 100);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('01.08.2023', 'z', 100);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('01.08.2023', 'a', 100);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('01.08.2023', 'b', 100);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('01.08.2023', 'c', 100);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('02.08.2023', 'x', 100);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('02.08.2023', 'y', 100);
insert into @temp(rowdate, code, val)values('02.08.2023', 'z', 100);


select 
tempTable.rowDate, 
tempTable.code, 
COALESCE(origTable.val, tempTable.val) as val 
from
    (select 
    a.rowDate, 
    b.code, 
    0 as val
    from (select distinct rowdate from @temp) as a 
    inner join (select distinct code from @temp) as b 
    on 1=1) 
    as tempTable
left join @temp as origTable
on tempTable.rowDate = origTable.rowDate 
and tempTable.code = origTable.code
order by tempTable.rowDate, tempTable.code
```